# Determining $\displaystyle\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) g(x)$ given conditions on $f$ and $g$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits

This was the 4th question that appreared in yesterday's JEE ADVANCED $2023$:

> Let $f:(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined as
> $$f(x)=\sqrt{n}$$ for all $x \in\left[\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n}\right),$
> where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> Let $g:(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a
> function such that $$\int_{x^2}^x \sqrt{\frac{1-t}{t}} d t<g(x) <2
> \sqrt{x}$$ for all $x \in(0,1)$.
>
> Then $$\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) g(x)$$
>
> **(A)** does NOT exist
>
> **(B)** is equal to 1
>
> **(C)** is equal to 2
>
> **(D)** is equal to 3

On noticing the domain of $f(x),$ I realised that the limit must be one-sided. But, this being an JEE Advanced exam, which usually asks really difficult questions and is known as the exam of exceptions, I thought that this might be some trap, so I didn't choose option A.

Then I observed the definite integral and substituted $t=\cos^2(\theta)$ and obtained $\tan(\theta).$ But I don't have any clue on how to accordingly change the integration limits.

What is a good solution strategy or thinking process for this exercise?

Comment: Please try a little harder to show your efforts. You said you understood the domain and the terms, explain further. Secondly, as you have written the limit does not exist because $\lim_{x\to0^-}$ is not defined.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you Ninad, I have elaborated more on how my thinking worked. Please kindly help if possible. Thank you friend

Comment: _"I don't have any clue on how to accordingly change the integration limits."_

You can employ the fundamental definition of calculus: If $\displaystyle{g(x) = \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)dt}$

$$g'(x)=\frac d {dx}\,\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)\,dt=f(b(x))\, b'(x)-f(a(x))\, a'(x)$$ to evaluate the  integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose for a moment the limit was actually intended to be $\lim_{x\to0^+}$ (since that is the only way to do anything interesting). Then we have that

$$\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}} \leq f(x) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$

from comparing the endpoints on the interval $\left[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right)$. This gives us the inequalities

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{x}}\int_{x^2}^x\sqrt{\frac{1-t}{t}}\:dt \leq \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)g(x) \leq \lim_{x\to 0^+}2$$

To take the limit as $x\to 0^+$ of the left hand side, we could use the fundamental theorem of calculus and an extended use of L'Hopital's rule. But as a timed exam shortcut tactic, assume the problem was made with a limit in mind and consider the substitution $t = xs$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \sqrt{1-x} \int_x^1 \sqrt{\frac{1-xs}{s}}ds = 1 \cdot \int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{1}{s}}ds = 2$$

as $x\to 0^+$. Thus the answer is $\boxed{\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)g(x) = 2}$ by squeeze theorem.

Of course if the limit truly was double sided, as discussed in the comments it would not exist.

Comment: Having read the JEE exam questions, it does seem like the questions are written with the ambient topologies in mind. So this limit may not have been double sided after all and $2$ was the intended limit.

Comment: Both functions are defined on $(0,1)$, where a distinction between a left- and right-sided limit does not make sense for $0$.

Comment: @JannikPitt educational assumptions in different countries are different, as in the American system I grew up in, the ambient topology in high school was always assumed to be $\Bbb{R}$ regardless of the function in front of us.